# How many rows have a value Mongodb/Mongoid?

Tags: ruby, mongodb, mongoid

I have a model with the following attributes:

```
follower.rb
----
creator_id, user_id
following_id, user_id
```

So a database might have an entries like:

```
creator_id, following_id
1, 2
3, 2
4, 2
5, 2
1, 3
2, 3
```

So in this case. 2 has 4 followers, and 3 has 2 followers.

Is it possible to generate a query that will return the information of total followers? Something like:

{
  2: 4,
  3: 2
}

any maybe sort them? Basically I want to get the top N users with the most followers.

Answer (score 1):

What you want in this case is the [aggregation framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) for MongoDB. There is no direct translation to "rails like" operations, so mongoid provides an accessor to the underlying driver to allow you to use the native methods:

```
Follower.collection.aggregate([
    { "$group" => {
        "_id" => "$creator_id",
        "count" => { "$sum" => 1 }
    }},
    { "$sort" => { "count" => -1 } },
    { "$limit" => 10 }
])
```

So [**`$group`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) does the grouping by the supplied field in the `_id` and the [**`$sum`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/) operator gets the count by that group.

The [**`$sort`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/sort/) stage orders the results so the highest count is on top, and the [**`$limit`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/limit/) pipeline stage determines how many results are returned.